# Testcafe: How to grab the text not from html code (selector) but in field on UI

Tags: html, testing, dom, automated-tests, testcafe

I need to extract parts of string from the text which was written in the field (input) on UI (This text is not in HTML code).
I am trying sth like this (but it does not work).

```
const textInput = await model.inputtTittle.textContent;
console.log(textInput)
```

Nothing return probably textContent take text from the selector, I was trying with .innerText but it also returned nothing.

And then I would like to write sth like this:

```
 if (textInput.length > 32)
     await t.typeText(model.inputTittle, textInput.substr(0, 30));
```

I hope that it will be work if I have the content of the field inputTittle.

Additional question:

This answer is hidden. This answer was deleted via review 16 hours ago by Jason Aller, Mark Rotteveel, Nico Haase, Botje.
This code works:

```
const textTittle = await model.inputTittle.value;
```

const textlength = textTittle.length

```
if (textlength>32)

{
console.log(textTittle.substr(0,30));
```

}
why i can not to writte shorter:

if (await model.inputTittle.value.length >32)

```
 { console.log(await model.inputTittle.value.substr(0,30));}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the entire [DOM Node Snapshot](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/using-selectors.html#dom-node-snapshot) with all properties in one object to check what properties you need. It is likely you need the `value` [property](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/dom-node-state.html#members-specific-to-element-nodes).

Comment: Hi Alex,
I have one additional question. (which is above)

Comment: Try to properly specify parens:
if ((await model.inputTittle.value).length >32)